# Convert month int value to formatted string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, time, formatting, nsdateformatter

I want to use the "LLL" string format of `NSDateFormatter` to get the proper string for the month name: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

All I have is the integer value of the month. For example, if the value is 5, then I need an output string of "May".

I don't want to use a switch. Is there any way I can use `NSDateFormatter` and apply `setDateFormat:` with "LLL" ?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to look at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is to get the [`monthSymbols`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBEHDCA) array from your formatter and index into that:

```
NSString * monthName = [formatter monthSymbols][monthInt];
```

If you want a date, though, `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` will get you there, letting you create an `NSDate` from whatever date elements you have.

```
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * comps = [NSDateComponents new];
[comps setMonth:monthVal];

NSDate * monthOnlyDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Now you can use your formatter on the date.

(Note that this date is basically meaningless aside from its use for this particular purpose; any unset properties -- hours, day, year -- of the components will be undefined, and the calendar will use its own choice of defaults for their values.)

Comment: But this will return complete date ? I need NSString like "May" etc.

Comment: What complete date? This will give you a date that, when passed through an `NSDateFormatter` whose format is `"LLL"`, produces a string with just the month name.